# Unable to use grunt-ssh to do tasks on server

Tags: javascript, ssh, gruntjs, grunt-ssh

i am trying to use grunt-ssh to automate deployment of server from my macbook pro.
So what i am trying to do with this task is to pull from my private bitbucket depository.

Deployment is looks okay once i do `grunt deploy` on bash but nothing gets pulled in server

This is my gruntfile:
    module.exports = function(grunt) {
        grunt.initConfig({
            sshconfig: {
                notify: {
                    host: 'mydomain.com',
                    port: 22,
                    username: 'root',
                    agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK
                 }
            },
            sshexec: {
                deploy: {
                    command: [
                        'cd notify', 
                        'git pull origin master',
                        'npm install',
                    ].join(' && '),
                    options: {
                    config: 'notify'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

```
    // Load the plugin that provides "sshevexc" task
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ssh');

    // Register new task, deploy
    grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['sshexec:deploy'], function(err){
        if(err)
            return false;

        grunt.log.write('Done deploying!').ok();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in your sshconfig:

agentForward: true